# Camera doesn't smoothly interpolate its rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, interpolation

I'm facing a problem in my scene. What i'm doing is there are two panels both panel has one button which performing `OnClick()` listener with the method name `RotateCamera()`.

[image: Image 1]

Also in hierarchy there is a `MainMenu` `gameobject` which attached with one script. When I play the scene and click on `panel one` button than `MainCamera` rotate with 90 angle to the direction of second panel. Script works fine but I want to smoothly rotate camera to that panel when I click on that button - right now, it is rotating instantly. I don't know what I'm doing wrong on this script.

```
public class CameraSmooth : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool check = false;
    private Transform from;
    private Transform to;

    void Start(){
        from = Camera.main.transform;
    }

    void Update(){
        if (to != null) {
            Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (from.rotation, to.rotation, 3 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    public void RotateCamera(){
        if (!check) {
            Camera.main.transform.Rotate (0,90f,0f);
            to = Camera.main.transform;
            check = true;
        }
        else if (check) {
            Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
            to = Camera.main.transform;
            check = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the issue that your camera rotates immediately? Because it looks like that's what your code currently does.

Comment: @Serlite yes it rotates immediately!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is that you're calling `Camera.main.transform.Rotate()` in `RotateCamera()`. This causes the rotation to be applied to the camera immediately, resulting in the instant rotation you're seeing.

Another small misconception - since `Transform` is a reference type, `from` and `to` always actually point to the same instance (the `Transform` of the camera)!  Lastly, the value of `3 * Time.deltaTime` will always average around 3/60, and will likely never end up close to 1, which is needed for an interpolation to be complete. As such, the following line:

```
Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (from.rotation, to.rotation, 3 * Time.deltaTime);
```

will not be able to do anything even if the first issue is addressed.

The situation calls for a different solution, in my view:

1. Storing the target rotations in `Quaternion` variables rather than setting them directly on the `Transform`, and keeping track of the camera's initial rotation
2. Maintaining a timer which keeps track of the progress of the rotation (or you can abandon `Slerp()` and just apply an incremental rotation directly, that's also a valid approach)

Here's my suggested update to your code:

```
public class CameraSmooth : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool check = false;
    private float rotationProgress = 1;
    private Quaternion initial;
    private Quaternion from;
    private Quaternion to;

    void Start(){
        // Cache the starting rotation, so we can calculate rotations relative to it
        initial = Camera.main.transform.rotation;
    }

    void Update(){
        if (rotationProgress < 1) {
            rotationProgress += 3 * Time.deltaTime;
            Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (from, to, rotationProgress);
        }
    }

    public void RotateCamera(){
        from = Camera.main.transform.rotation;
        rotationProgress = 0;

        if (!check) {
            to = initial * Quaternion.Euler(0,90f,0f);
            check = true;
        }
        else if (check) {
            to = initial;
            check = false;
        }
    }
}
```

(Haven't tested this code, so please let me know if there are any issues.) Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions!